# Any one have used Posix pthread win32 library, dll files

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, pthreads

I am trying to setup a mqueue in win32 env, but need pthread win32 lib, http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/. Any one knows how to link it to my VS project?
Thanks

Comment: You might want to mention linking to a VS project in the title of your question to make it more specific.

Comment: @suszterpatt - q is tagged visual-c++ already

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to one of the Visual C++ `.lib` files, which are named differently depending on what exception handling you wish in the library.  See the FAQ [here](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/faq.html), items 2. and 3. for further details.

```
In general:
        pthread[VG]{SE,CE,C}.dll
        pthread[VG]{SE,CE,C}.lib

where:
        [VG] indicates the compiler
        V       - MS VC
        G       - GNU C

        {SE,CE,C} indicates the exception handling scheme
        SE      - Structured EH
        CE      - C++ EH
        C       - no exceptions - uses setjmp/longjmp

For example:
        pthreadVSE.dll  (MSVC/SEH)
        pthreadGCE.dll  (GNUC/C++ EH)
        pthreadGC.dll   (GNUC/not dependent on exceptions)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already choose pthreadVC2.dll, that is correct?

Comment: Umm... that's not in the list.  I would have expected you to want some exception handling in C++, i.e. either `VCE` or `VSE`.  Any idea what the `2` means?  Maybe to distinguish Win32 vs Win64? I cannot currently download this to check, sorry.

Comment: FYI: ftp://sourceware.org/pub/pthreads-win32/prebuilt-dll-2-8-0-release/, I am not very familiar with different EH, one is just throw exception, the other is throw exception and destroy the object. I want to choose the second one, but I don't know which version works like this.

Comment: You need `VCE` for the second, that's C++ exception handling